# How to measure the delay of one single inverter in ASIC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, measurement, inverter, delay, asic

In practice, is it feasible for a chip manufacture to reliably and accurately measure the delay of one single inverter in ASIC? If it is, how can one go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to measure the delay of a single inverter by itself precisely.  They are so fast on modern integrated circuits that getting an accurate measurement of the delay is not easy.  Generally, maufacturers will construct something called a ring oscillator and then measure it's oscillation frequency.  A ring oscillator consists of a loop of an odd number of inverters.  It will oscillate spontaneously with a period of the product of the number of inverters and the propagation delay of the inverters.  All manufacturers need to do to measure the delay is power up their ring oscillator and connect it to a frequency counter.  Then you take the number of inverters in the oscillator and divide by the frequency to get the delay on a single inverter.

Comment: Can we just build a ring oscillator with one single inverter and measure the frequency of the ring's output?

Comment: You can, but you can't just connect the output to the input.  If you do that, it won't oscillate, it will just hang out at Vdd/2.  You need to add some delay so that it will actually be able to turn on and off, either in the form of more inverters or in the form of a long transmission line.

Comment: That's interesting! So why does it hang out at Vdd/2?

Comment: A CMOS inverter is built with two MOSFET transistors, one PMOS and one NMOS.  When the input is high, the PMOS is off and the NMOS is on, pulling the output low.  When the input is low, the PMOS is on and the NMOS is off, pulling the output high.  If the input and output are directly connected together, the output voltage will quickly settle to Vdd/2 as if it is any higher, the NMOS wil turn on more and pull it down and if it is any lower, the PMOS will turn on more and pull it up.  This 'balancing' effect is used in DRAM sense amplifiers to increase sensitivity.

Comment: Is a ring of 3 inverters good enough to produce an oscillating signal? If not, is there a minimum number of inverters that we need to have in order to build a ring oscillator? If so, how do people come up with such number?

Comment: You need the propagation delay around the loop to be longer than the rise or fall time of a single inverter.  3 inverters may be sufficient, but not likely.  It will likely oscillate, but the inverters will not turn on or off fully.  Usually I think test chains are on the order 30 inverters or so.  More inverters means the test signal is lower in frequency and hence easier to deal with and the inverter rise and fall times are not likely to interfere significantly with the propagation delay that you're trying to characterize.

Comment: Reference to ring oscillator:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator